# Whitespace handling in NSXML parsing

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

When i parse a html file with NSXMLParser. I couldnot avoid the whitespace in html file.
For Example
`<html>       <body><p>sample text.   This is sample text     </p></body></html>`

In found characters function i am getting whitespace also. I dont want the white space within html tag. but i want the white space and new line characters in p tag(also h1, div, etc). any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no useful inforamation you need from HTML tag then just ignore it while parsing.
You can simply parse `<p>,<div>` tags alone, which will remove spaces by itself.

For instance

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {


if([elementName isEqualToString:@"HTML"])
{
    NSLog(@"ignore");
}
```

Comment: Thanks . but, if there is a white space in body tag means, what can i do? Is there any default handler for ignorablewhitespace. what is the use of ignorablewhitespace delegate function. it doesnt work for me.